# Estou com problema em um site que fiz usando vuejs, erro 404 NoSuchKey

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Desenvolvi um site em vuejs utilizei vue-router para os caminhos, porem quando acesso a pagina ela carrega normal, porem quando estou em um /services e recarrego a pagina da o erro

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>services</Key>
<RequestId>000000000</RequestId>
<HostId>sadsasadsadasdasdassaasddas=</HostId>
</Error>
```

antes estava dando erro 403 forbien, agora 404 me ajudem ai, se quiser ver o repositorio esta no github meu

https://github.com/danielurba/site-personal-car-vuejs

site que esta dando problema
https://www.personalcarcvel.com.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este pode ser um problema da configuração de seu vue-router ou no servidor.

Verifique as configurações de sua rota se elas possuem uma tratativa para acessos diretos ou atualizações, que são novas requisições ao servidor.

Ambos os casos são explicados aqui:
[History Mode vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Pode tentar adicionar em sua criação do routes o seguinte:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    routes
})
```

Se estiver usando Apache tente adicionar o seguinte ao seu .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```